# How to read a xml in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005, xml-parsing

I have this query

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom') 
select 
cast(idsku as int) idsku,
cast(entregado as int) entregado from #final1 final FOR XML AUTO, ROOT ('clientesxml'), ELEMENTS
```

this return

```
<clientesxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <final>
    <idsku>191</idsku>
    <entregado>159</entregado>
  </final>
</clientesxml>
```

My question how do I create a stored procedure which reads the XML returned and converts it into a `#tempTable` ?

Comment: Are you looking to insert the data back into the original format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few similar methods that may come in handy when creating your proc:

```
-- Declare some xml
declare @xml xml = '<clientesxml xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <final>
    <idsku>191</idsku>
    <entregado>159</entregado>
  </final>
</clientesxml>'

-- Shred the xml
;with xmlnamespaces (default 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom') 
select x.Record.value('idsku[1]', 'int') as idsku
    , x.Record.value('entregado[1]', 'int') as entregado
from @xml.nodes('//clientesxml/final') as x (Record)

-- Shred and insert the xml into a new temp table
;with xmlnamespaces (default 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom') 
select x.Record.value('idsku[1]', 'int') as idsku
    , x.Record.value('entregado[1]', 'int') as entregado
into #tempTable
from @xml.nodes('//clientesxml/final') as x (Record)

-- Shred and insert the xml into an existing temp table
;with xmlnamespaces (default 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom') 
insert into #tempTable (idsku, entregado)
select x.Record.value('idsku[1]', 'int') as idsku
    , x.Record.value('entregado[1]', 'int') as entregado
from @xml.nodes('//clientesxml/final') as x (Record)
```

Comment: this inserts all my records? or only one record?

Comment: All records contained in @xml.  A `where` clause could filter them.